# Refill data on edit dynamic check box in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have created a component 'menu-assign' for my project in Angular 6. It consists of a dynamic checkbox and it is working for creating new. But for editing I can not refill existing database data to the check box. This is my template file:

```
<tbody  *ngFor="let menu of resultMenus; let i = index">
    <td>{{ menu.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ menu.url }}<input type="hidden" name="menu[]" id="menu" value="{{ menu.id }}"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_view[]" id="can_view" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_add[]" id="can_add" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_edit[]" id="can_edit" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_delete[]" id="can_delete" value="1"></td>
</tbody>
```

This is my API call:

```
"data":[
{
"id": 9,
"user_id": 2,
"menu_id": 4,
"status": 1,
"can_add": 0,
"can_edit": 0,
"can_view": 1,
"can_delete": 0
},
{
"id": 10,
"user_id": 2,
"menu_id": 3,
"status": 1,
"can_add": 0,
"can_edit": 0,
"can_view": 0,
"can_delete": 0
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checked property can be used

<tbody  *ngFor="let menu of resultMenus; let i = index">
    <td>{{ menu.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ menu.url }}<input type="hidden" name="menu[]" id="menu" value="{{ menu.id }}"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_view[]" id="can_view" value="1" [checked]="menu.can_view"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_add[]" id="can_add" value="1" [checked]="menu.can_add"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_edit[]" id="can_edit" value="1"
[checked]="menu.can_edit"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="can_delete[]" id="can_delete" value="1"
[checked]="menu.can_delete"></td>
</tbody>
```